# Archlinux - Delete files in different subdir with date name

Tags: linux, arch-linux, automation, cron, youtube-dl

I need your help to find a way to cron-delete somes files in multiple subdir based on date format in the name.

I use this script in youtube-dl:

```
youtube-dl --yes-playlist --download-archive archive.txt --continue --ignore-errors --no-overwrites --dateafter now-1week -o '%(uploader)s/%(upload_date)s - %(title)s' -a rss.txt
```

With the script I have this:

```
Videos
│   rss.txt
│   archive.txt    
│
└───Artiste_Youtube_01
│   │   20170906 - Title.mkv
│   │   YYYYMMDD - Title.mkv
|   
└───Artiste_Youtube_02
    │   YYYYMMDD - Title.mkv
    │   YYYYMMDD - Title.mkv
```

And I want to auto-delete the mkv older than 1week+1day.

I have see this:

```
find ./my_dir -mtime +10 -type f -delete
```

It good for the date of creation but not for the named date of the file.

Can you help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare the name prefix to a date. You can get the comparison item easily with: `date -d '-10 days' +%Y%m%d`. Then you loop over your files:

```
cutDate=$(date -d '-10 days' +%Y%m%d)
for f in */*.mkv
do
    prefix=$(sed -r 's:.*/([0-9]{8}) -.*:\1:' <<<"$f")
    [[ $prefix < $cutDate ]] && rm "$f"
done
```

If you have more subdirectory levels, add more stars in the `for` pattern:
`for f in */*/*.mkv`

(**warning: untested**)

Comment: Thanks for reponse. But doesn't work because I use subfolder...

Comment: I have try with an other folder structure, I have this...
[link](https://framapic.org/1OO50VrhvtI5/3Nq7IHdQMM2Y)

Comment: Updated answer: added double quotes in the `rm` command, and use more stars if more directory levels.